# IOS TextField without having zero

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Hi I'm creating a iphone app and one of the conditions is that the user should not be able to enter “0” as the first digit of his/her response (when the UITextField as its placeholder value) unless the correct answer is 0.

What I have so far is but it lets me enter a 0 still but doesn't let 100 which should happen

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let leadingZero = textField.text?.rangeOfString("0")
    let replacementZero = string.rangeOfString("0")

    if leadingZero != nil && replacementZero != nil {
        return false
    }


    return true
}
```

Comment: Your problem will solve or you still face some issue ?

Comment: I tried the suggested solutions but I can still enter 0 as a number or it breaks my other part of the code. The hint said to use delegation.

Comment: did you want code for this problem or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a correctAnswer variable

```
//make it true or false depending whether your correct answer is zero
var correctAnswerIsZero = false
```

Add a target to the textfield

```
myTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textfieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
```

Defination of target

```
func textfieldDidChange(textfield:UITextField) {
    if correctAnswerIsZero {
    } else {
        //if correct answer is not zero
        if textfield.text?.characters.first == "0"  {
            print("You have entered 0, so deleting it")
            textfield.text = ""
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to check whether the textField is empty, and refuse to allow a 0 to be entered if it is, you can do the following:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    return (textField.hasText || string != "0") ? true : false
}
```

hasText ignores placeholder text, so that won't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

**// Create Textfield action method Editing Changed**

```
@IBAction func TextfieldCheck(sender: AnyObject) {
    if YOURTEXTFIELD.text?.characters.count > 0 {
        let str : String = YOURTEXTFIELD.text!
        if str.characters.count < 3 {
            if str .containsString("0")
            {
                YOURTEXTFIELD.text = ""
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Your problem will be solve now . If any problem face with my this code then tell me